# How to save htop output to file?

Tags: htop

How can I save the output of `htop` to a file? With `top`, I can run

```
top -b -n1 > top.txt
```

where `-b` specifies batch mode and `-n` specifies the number of iterations.

But the `man` page of `htop` doesn't offer such a possibility.

Is taking a screenshot the only way?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

[Ron](https://askubuntu.com/users/402004/ron) provided a link to [htop output to human readable file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17534591) and a quote from the top-voted answer by the developer of htop.

However, a little further down on the same page, there's [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30224271) which uses ANSI to HTML conversion. Briefly, install `aha` from the software center and then run:

```
echo q | htop | aha --black --line-fix > htop.html
```

Here's what the first few lines look like:

```
  1  [|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||                                    42.9%]     Tasks: 73, 251 thr; 1 running
  2  [||||||                                                                7.1%]     Load average: 0.28 0.32 0.32 
  Mem[||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||                              581/3916MB]     Uptime: 03:09:25
  Swp[                                                                  0/4056MB]
  PID USER      PRI  NI  VIRT   RES   SHR S CPU% MEM%   TIME+  Command          
 9785 dkb        20   0 31544  2464  1312 R 22.2  0.1  0:00.09 htop             
 3503 dkb        20   0 1065M 59684 16344 S  7.4  1.5  6:25.43 mpv --profile=pseudo-gui -- file:///home/dkb/Downloads/ONX
    1 root       20   0 33760  3088  1488 S  0.0  0.1  0:01.62 /sbin/init        
  276 root       20   0 19472   652   460 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.19 upstart-udev-bridge --daemon
  281 root       20   0 52592  2640  1016 S  0.0  0.1  0:00.76 /lib/systemd/systemd-udevd --daemon
  577 root       20   0 15256   632   388 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.05 upstart-socket-bridge --daemon
  662 root       20   0 15272   416   200 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.04 upstart-file-bridge --daemon
  677 syslog     20   0  249M  1304   836 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.01 rsyslogd          
  678 syslog     20   0  249M  1304   836 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.00 rsyslogd          
  679 syslog     20   0  249M  1304   836 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.02 rsyslogd          
  675 syslog     20   0  249M  1304   836 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.04 rsyslogd          
  680 messagebu  20   0 39860  1968  1044 S  0.0  0.0  0:00.52 dbus-daemon --system --fork
```

Comment: For those wondering: piping `q` to `htop` quits it immediately.

Comment: I like to add `stty` to expand the rows such that every process is in the html file: `stty rows 9999; echo q | htop | aha --black --line-fix > htop.html`

Answer (score 18):

Right [from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17534591/htop-output-to-human-readable-file) the author of `htop`:

> No, there's no "nice" way to get the output of htop piped into a file.
>   It is an interactive application and uses terminal redraw routines to
>   produce its interface (therefore, piping it makes as much sense as,
>   for example, piping vim into a text file -- you'll get similar
>   results).
>
> To get the information about your processes in a text format, use
>   `ps`. For example, `ps auxf > file.txt` gives you lots of easy to parse
>   information (or ps aux if you do not wish tree-formatting -- see man
>   ps for more options).

Answer (score 11):

Try this command; it does what you want. You just need to install `aha` and `html2text` first.

```
echo q | htop -C | aha --line-fix | html2text -width 999 | grep -v "F1Help" | grep -v "xml version=" > file.txt
```

Answer (score 6):

this can get colorful output same as you see when htop running.

### 1. save terminal output to file

```
echo | htop  > /tmp/htop.out

## OR

sleep 3 | htop  > /tmp/htop.out
```

//htop.out has `terminal save/load console_sequence`

### 2. show output in terminal

```
head -c -10 /tmp/htop.out  | tail -c +10
```

// just use head & tail strip the `screen reset console_sequence`
// `10` bytes was roughly

// only show last screen in htop.out

### X. explanation

`vim /tmp/htop.out`,

will see something like this ( @ ubuntu18, gnome-terminal, TERM=xterm )

```
^[[?1049h^[[22; .... ^[[?1049l^[[23;0;0t^M^[[?1l^[>
```

- `^[[?1049h`: switch to alternative screen @ begin of htop
- `^[[?1049l`: switch to normal screen  @ end of htop

htop.out is not blank, it just show content in alternative screen, no effecit with normal screen.

the `head` `tail` strip out those special sequence, let it show content at normal screen.

@brad

// seems the `watch` command also use this mechanism

--- refs: ---
https://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-The-Alternate-Screen-Buffer
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/288962/what-does-1049h-and-1h-ansi-escape-sequences-do
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11023929/using-the-alternate-screen-in-a-bash-script

Comment: can you explain this in a little more detail?  "just use head & tail strip the screen reset console_sequence"

Comment: @brad strip out some special char sequence, ( such as `echo -ne "\e[10;50H \e[1J"`, will move cursor and erase display, ( more detail found at `man console_sequence`

Answer (score 5):

I normally do the following:

```
top
control-c
```

and then scroll up so I can copy/paste:

```
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~$ top
top - 18:58:05 up 13 min,  2 users,  load average: 0,18, 0,35, 0,24
Tasks: 252 total,   1 running, 251 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
%Cpu(s):  3,4 us,  0,7 sy,  0,5 ni, 95,3 id,  0,1 wa,  0,0 hi,  0,0 si,  0,0 st
KiB Mem:  12190608 total,  2007692 used, 10182916 free,    50292 buffers
KiB Swap: 24414204 total,        0 used, 24414204 free.   739236 cached Mem

  PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND     
 1093 rinzwind  20   0  364616   8824   7252 S   6,2  0,1   0:00.94 ibus-daemon 
 2525 rinzwind  20   0   29192   3048   2540 R   6,2  0,0   0:00.02 top         
    1 root      20   0  185008   5564   3840 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.77 systemd     
    2 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kthreadd    
    3 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/0 
    5 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kworker/0:+ 
    7 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.32 rcu_sched   
    8 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 rcu_bh      
    9 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.09 rcuos/0     
   10 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 rcuob/0     
   11 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 migration/0 
   12 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 watchdog/0  
   13 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 watchdog/1  
   14 root      rt   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 migration/1 
   15 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 ksoftirqd/1 
   16 root      20   0       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.04 kworker/1:0 
   17 root       0 -20       0      0      0 S   0,0  0,0   0:00.00 kworker/1:+ 
rinzwind@schijfwereld:~$
```