# How would you best identify possible bottlenecks in your system?

Tags: hardware, performance

I notice that in some tasks, like drawing or video editing or games, sometimes I get performance dips that are pretty annoying. And before throwing money at the problem and buying better hardware, I would like to pinpoint what hardware must be replaced or if it's just some programs executing poorly because they run through wine or similar issues.

For that I would need to figure out how to log CPU/GPU/RAM usage into a file while running those applications, and I would really appreciate if anyone has more ideas to what other possible bottlenecks I should watch out for.

Comment: Start by installing  `htop`. See also https://askubuntu.com/questions/726333/how-to-save-htop-output-to-file

Comment: It is a start, but the issue I have with checking these kind of live monitoring tools like top or the gnome system monitor is that the applications are not running consistently slow, but just have occasional dips in performance, and if I'm using the whole screen by the time I switch to check it's too late.

Ideally I would like a list of sampled overall references, so after I'm done I can make a graph of how the hardware performed over that time and see if the system overall is frequently running short on something.