# Output produced by cron get truncated

Tags: command-line, cron

I just created a script to output `htop` automatically every n minutes using this method → https://askubuntu.com/a/726661/253251, I put the script on crontab so it can be executed daily. But the output produced by cron was incomplete.

[image]

However, if I execute the command manually, there will be no truncated text.

[image]

Is there any settings that I can tweak to achieve full output in cron?

### UPDATE

I have already tried Waltinator suggestion, it doesn't work and it stretch the output so long which is not what I want.

[image]
<sub>Screenshot</sub>

How to make output similar to the one executed manually ?

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading  the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages you got on your system. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.

Comment: Try `export COLUMNS=500` before your `htop` command.

Comment: @waltinator The bar became extremely long https://i.imgur.com/ezrnUta.png

Comment: If you want to replicate the second image (which also appears truncated), I guess `export COLUMNS=120` or similar would work. Or any other number you deem appropriate. I can't imagine you want unlimited width.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio You're right, I just noticed that. Thanks for pointing it out !

Comment: @Liso please add exactly the commands you used for each screenshot. Otherwise it is quite difficult to guess...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me that you just have to pick the "right" value for `COLUMNS`.  In a way, your manual method did that as well since you widened the window to some suitable value before you ran `htop`.

I don't think there is a "magical way" to do it, unless you ran `ps` or some similar command, find out the length of the longest command being run, and then set that to the value of `COLUMNS` (plus some more columns for everything that appears to the left of it), and then run `htop`.

I guess this could be achieved with this code:

```
ps -aef | awk -v OFS='\t' '{ $1=$1; print }' | cut -f 8 | awk 'length > max_length { max_length = length; longest_line = $0 } END { print longest_line }' | wc -c
```

Credit for this goes to these two pages:  [1](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/535024/how-to-convert-space-separated-file-into-tab-separated) and [2](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24509/how-to-print-the-longest-line-in-a-file), which I just copied from.

The part on the left isn't variable in length, so you can add it on as a constant.  Then have your script set `COLUMNS` using this value.  I'm not sure if this will work...  Good luck!

Comment: While this is not exactly the solution, but your answer gave me direction to the workaround. Thanks !

Comment: @Liso Oh?  You're welcome!  Good to hear it helped you out!